# Why doesn't this quicksort show anything in the browser?

Tags: php, quicksort

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

function quicksort($seq) 
{
    if(!count($seq)) {return $seq;}
    $pivot= $seq[0];
    $low = $high = array();
    $length = count($seq);
    for($i=1; $i < $length; $i++) 
    {
        if($seq[$i] <= $pivot) 
        {
            $low []= $seq[$i];
        } else {
            $high []= $seq[$i];
               }
    }
    return array_merge(quicksort($low), array($pivot), quicksort($high));

 $numbers = array(2,5,6,8,3,6,4,45,23,456,23,6,90,5,2,156,2,1,3,12,48,561,1,168);
 $words = array('gr','sdfg','ik','shrt','jy','bcnv',' 0','0','01','_a','ass');


 print_r(quicksort($numbers));
 print_r(quicksort($words));


highlight_file(quicksort.php);

?>
```

The screen is blank. PHP error log says unexpected end of file. 
I'm tired and might be overlooking a semi-colon, but I can't find it.

Comment: 1. You are missing "}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a curly bracket at the end of your function definition

Answer (score 0):

Replace your function with this...

```
function quicksort($seq) 
{
    if(!count($seq)) {return $seq;}
    $pivot= $seq[0];
    $low = $high = array();
    $length = count($seq);
    for($i=1; $i < $length; $i++) 
    {
        if($seq[$i] <= $pivot) 
        {
            $low []= $seq[$i];
        } else {
            $high []= $seq[$i];
        }
    }
    return array_merge(quicksort($low), array($pivot), quicksort($high));
}
```